# phpmyadmin where condition in mysql union got sintax error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried that in phpmyadmin (4.5.2) and work OK:

```
(SELECT 'db1' as DB_NAME, db1_col1, null as dbd2_col1 FROM db1.db1_table1)
UNION
(SELECT 'db2' as DB_NAME, null as dbd1_col1, db2_col1 FROM db2.db2_table1)

The result is:
DB_NAME      db1_col1      dbd2_col1
 db1       DB1_col1_val1     NULL
 db2           NULL       DB2_col1_val1
```

But if i try to add a where clause I got sintax error:

```
(SELECT 'db1' as DB_NAME, db1_col1, null as dbd2_col1 
    FROM db1.db1_table1 
    WHERE db1_col1 = 'DB1_col1_val1'
)
UNION
(SELECT 'db2' as DB_NAME, null as dbd1_col1, db2_col1  
    FROM db2.db2_table1 
    WHERE db2_col1 = 'DB1_col1_val1'
)
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
>   (' at line 4

This made me crazy!

Nevertheless, when I tried it on console, it worked as espected:

```
mysql> (SELECT 'db1' as DB_NAME, db1_col1, null as dbd2_col1
    -> FROM db1.db1_table1
    -> WHERE db1_col1 = 'DB1_col1_val1'
    -> )
    -> UNION
    -> (SELECT 'db2' as DB_NAME, null as dbd1_col1, db2_col1
    -> FROM db2.db2_table1
    -> WHERE db2_col1 = 'DB1_col1_val1'
    -> );
+---------+---------------+-----------+
| DB_NAME | db1_col1      | dbd2_col1 |
+---------+---------------+-----------+
| db1     | DB1_col1_val1 | NULL      |
+---------+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the question:

Is this a bug of phpmyadmin or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it worked in the console, it is probably a phpmyadmin bug. My guess is that phpmyadmin tried to insert its `limit` clause after the closing parentheses of the 1st query.

UPDATE

Apparently, this is the same bug as fixed [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11744). If you upgrade to phpmyadmin v4.5.3.0 or later, then this bug is no longer there.

Comment: It should be this and the moral i think is: Use the console! :)

Comment: Another lesson perhaps: don't use outdated software.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of phpmyadmin documentation indicates you forgot the ; at the end of your request.  It was present on the console documentation.  Just a thought.

Comment: Nope! It was only a typo. I have tried also with ; and got same error. @Shadow answer is the good answer